# linq to entities retrieve database table row value and display as label.Text C# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities

Using LINQ to Entities.  NOT SQLConnections or any other method.

I have a webpage where I need to display the 'ID' from one DataTable and the corresponding 'Name' from another DataTable, both in the same database.  The ID and Name should be displayed as lblOrderId.Text = OrderId.ToString(); and lblName.Text = Name.ToString(); respectively.
Does not have to be a string, I just want the values from the Database in the labels.

As it stand now I am not getting any of the label text, but if I use the code right at the bottom of this all I get is the order and delivery dates.

Datatable containing OrderId has two columns; OrderId being autogenerated and sitting in column 0, and ProductId.

Datatable containing Name has 6 columns, Name being in column 1 as column 0 holds autogenerated customer ID

All I need is the last added Name and ID to be displayed as labels.

I have been researching this on this site and others for the last 5 hours and cannot seem to find a solution which suits my needs.  It's all SQL Connections and a sparse sprinkling of Database values to text boxes.

Please see code below with what I have achieved, and if you require any further coding or information please do not hesitate to ask.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions or assistance you can provide.

ASPX.CS (back end)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Entities myEntities = new Entities())
        {
             int OrderId = // Not sure what to put here, but if I don't have it I get the error *The name OrderId does not exist in the current context*
             var orderId = (from ord in myEntities.Orders
                           where ord.OrderId.Equals(OrderId) // Error here
                           select ord).Last();                

            lblOrderID.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblOrderID.Text = orderId.ToString();
```

Facing the exact same error with the method below concerning the Name.  Both methods are contained within the same Using Entities {} curly brackets.

```
var name = (from ord in myEntities.Customer
                        where ord.Name.Equals(Name)
                        select ord).Last();

            lblName.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblName.Text = name.ToString();
```

Closing the Using Entities {} curly brackets, but still inside the Page_Load {} curly brackets I have the following code to add the order date and delivery date as seen below

```
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime DeliveryDate = date.AddDays(5);

        lblDate.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        lblDeliveryDate.ForeColor = Color.Red;

        lblDate.Text = date.ToLongDateString();
        lblDeliveryDate.Text = DeliveryDate.ToLongDateString();
```

Full block of Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Entities myEntities = new Entities())
        {
            //int OrderId = Convert.ToInt32(); // Not sure what to put here, but if I don't have it I get the error *The name OrderId does not exist in the current context*

            var orderId = (from ord in myEntities.Orders
                           where ord.OrderId.Equals(OrderId)// Error here
                           select ord).Last();

            lblOrderID.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblOrderID.Text = orderId.ToString();


            var name = (from ord in myEntities.Customer
                        where ord.Name.Equals(Name)
                        select ord).Last();

            lblName.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblName.Text = name.ToString();
        }

        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime DeliveryDate = date.AddDays(5);

        lblDate.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        lblDeliveryDate.ForeColor = Color.Red;

        lblDate.Text = date.ToLongDateString();
        lblDeliveryDate.Text = DeliveryDate.ToLongDateString();
    }
```

ASPX (front end)

```
    <p>
            Hi 
        <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            Thank you for shopping at Cineplex.<br />
            <br />

            Your Order ID number is: 
        <asp:Label ID="lblOrderID" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
            <br />

            Your order was placed on:
        <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
            <br />

            Delivery date:
        <asp:Label ID="lblDeliveryDate" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </p>
```

Hardcoding the Name and Order ID and removing the entities and querys as can be seen using the code below at the backend works a treat, but that's not acceptable.  The customer needs to view their Order ID upon successful purchase.
The only consolation here is that I get a value in all four labels the client can read.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblName.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        lblName.Text = "User";

        lblOrderID.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        lblOrderID.Text = "1";

        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime DeliveryDate = date.AddDays(5);

        lblDate.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        lblDeliveryDate.ForeColor = Color.Red;

        lblDate.Text = date.ToLongDateString();
        lblDeliveryDate.Text = DeliveryDate.ToLongDateString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is all about querying something from the database. You could remove all ASP stuff from the query, as it only distracts from what your problem is.

Instead you should show us the entity classes (Order, Customer). As I understand, you want the `Order.OrderId` and the `Customer.Name` (of the customer who's order it is) for a specific order, of which you don't know how it is identified.

Assuming you go with the usual Customer/Order sample model, your entities must look about like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId; // identifies a customer
    public string Name; // the customer's name
    public ICollection<Order> Orders; // collection of customer's orders
}

public class Order
{
    public int OrderId; // identifies an order
    public int CustomerId { get; } // ID of the customer who's order it is.
    public Customer Customer { get; } // The Customer entity of that customer
}
```

Inside the Page_Load (leaving away what is not relevant)

```
// 1st find out the ID of the one and only order the page is about
int orderId = 4711; // can't help here - where do you intend to get it from?

// 2nd retrieve from DB whatever we need later
string customerName;
using (var myEntities = new Entities())
{
    var orderInfo = (
        from order in myEntities.Orders
        where order.OrderId == orderId
        select new { CustomerName = order.Customer.Name }
        ).SingleOrDefault();
    if (orderInfo == null) // error handling if orderId is bad
        throw new Exception("No such order found.");
    customerName = orderInfo.CustomerName;
}

// 3rd use what we know to update controls
lblName.Text = customerName;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  It really is much appreciated as are your comments regarding posing a more concise question.  As for the int orderId = 4711; // can't help here - where do you intend to get it from?  I had intended to retrieve it from the orders table I have inside the database.  The orders table contains the an autogenerated OrderId and CustomerId along with the date the order was placed.

Answer (score 0):

Result.
I saved the initial variables in two different sessions on the aspx.cs page where they were created like so:

```
int custID = Cust.CustomerId;
Session["CustID"] = Cust.CustomerId;

int newOrderID = ord.OrderId;
Session["newOrderID"] = ord.OrderId;
```

Then on the aspx.cs page I wanted to query the database table I did the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["CustID"] != null)
        {
            int CID = (int)Session["CustID"];

            using (var myEntities = new Entities())
            {
                var CustName = (from customer in myEntities.Customer
                                where customer.CustomerId == (CID)
                                select customer.Name).SingleOrDefault();
                if (CustName == null) // error handling if customer name does not exist
                    throw new Exception("No such Customer found.");
                lblName.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                lblName.Text = CustName;
            }
        }
        if (Session["newOrderID"] != null)
        {
            int OID = (int)Session["CustID"];

            using (var myEntities = new Entities())
            {
                var OrderNum = (from order in myEntities.Orders
                                where order.OrderId == (OID)
                                select order.OrderId).SingleOrDefault();
                if (OrderNum == 0) // error handling if customer name does not exist
                    throw new Exception("No such Order found.");
                lblOrderID.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                lblOrderID.Text = OrderNum.ToString();
            }
        }

        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime DeliveryDate = date.AddDays(5);

        lblDate.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        lblDeliveryDate.ForeColor = Color.Red;

        lblDate.Text = date.ToLongDateString();
        lblDeliveryDate.Text = DeliveryDate.ToLongDateString();
    }
```

Thank you to those of you who gave advice and suggestions.  Much appreciated.

Comment: (1) CustomerId is redundant: If you have the OrderId in the Session, the CustomerId is given. (2) Use the power of EF to get all you need in one Query, similar to how I did.

Comment: Thank you Tinudu.  I have managed to solve the issue, but in future I will use something closer to your method as it just makes sense.  Writing unnecessary code is not only timely, but allows for the possibility of errors to creep in and get lost.